# Pull month name and year from main sheet to separate sheet

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a main sheet that contains a date column (D). Date is as `01/01/2010`.
I want to be able to pull month name and year in a VBA subroutine to sheet1 based on other user input. Here is some of the code I'm trying to make work, this is in a sub in mainsheet:

```
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("mainsheet")
    With ws2 
     '=YEAR(mainsheet!D2)
      ' mn = Text([Date], "mmmm")
       my= .Cells(Year(1, 3))
    End With
```

After I get the correct month and year (January 2010) I plan to put that in a variable that goes into E1 on sheet1.

I've moved things around, I've used quotes, I've tried range ... it's just not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("mainsheet")
    With ws2
     Dim y As Integer, m As String
     y = Year(.Range("D2"))
     m = MonthName(Month(.Range("D2")))
    End With
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    With ws2
     .Range("E1") = m & " " & y
    End With
```

Comment: I get a type mismatch?

Comment: That means you don't have a valid date in D2. Enter a valid date and try again.

Comment: I just hovered over the .Range and I get 3219101... Interesting as when I go to the main sheet it says it's formatted as a date?? Do I need to format it before or after or something?

Comment: No, the format is not important. It is used to display the data in whatever way you want. You need to enter a valid date in the cell. Try entering 2015-01-01 for testing.

Answer (score 0):

To get the month use:

```
.cells(1,5) = MonthName(Month(.Cells(1,3).value)
```

to get year:

```
.cells(1,5) = Year(.Cells(1,3).value)
```

edit:

If all you want is the month and date from one cell into another then

```
 Sheets("TargetSheetName").Cells(1,5) = format(Sheets("DataSheetName").Cells(1,3), "mmmm yyyy")
```

Comment: Thanks, that's not the actual issue, it's more pulling it in the sub via the worksheet code. I can not seem to access the cells correctly. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with to solve your issue. Given your date is in cell D2 on the mainsheet page this will put the month and year in the format "January 2010" into cell E1 on the same page.

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("mainsheet")
    With ws2
        yr = Year(.Range("D2"))
        mn = Format(.Range("D2"), "MMMM")
        .Cells(1, 5) = mn & " " & yr
        .Cells(1, 5).NumberFormat = "MMMM YYYY"         
    End With
End Sub
```